# Return Count Value back as 0 if emtpy or none

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am running the following query in our database and I am trying to get the count value back as 0 if none are present, but having problems doing so. Could someone help assist and explain how to accomplish this

```
select state, count(phone_number) from VOIP_PHONE_NUMBER_POOL
where status = 3
group by state
order by state asc;
```

For example, currently my query is returning something back like this

```
State  Count

AZ     25
```

When I want it to return the empty values and look like this

```
State  Count

AZ     25
CA     0
```

Comment: Is there another table that has all the valid `state` values that you would want to appear in your result?

Comment: Unfortunately not, its limited ot this table. I did some research before posting and I know I could do this with a left join if it was. I'm kind of stumped how I can do it without that though.

Comment: How do you know which `state` values you want to appear in the final result, then?  If `VOIP_PHONE_NUMBER_POOL` has all the state values, just not with `status = 3`, you could do the self-join that @LittleFoot suggests.  But that is going to be very expensive assuming this is a reasonably large table.

Comment: There ain't no such thing as a free lunch, @Justin :)

Comment: @Littlefoot - Totally agreed.  Unless the data volumes are really weird, though, I'd strongly prefer to create a new `state` table to have the rows you want.  Particularly if the large fact table has some data quality issues (I've seen plenty of systems that had data for 70 or 80 of the 50 US states :-) )

Comment: I agree, @Justin. Data model seems to be *wrong*; at least, the `voip_phone_number_pool` table isn't normalized. As you said, `state` should be a separate table, referenced from the `voip_...`. Oh well, my query was just an example of how to "solve" this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
     SELECT s.state,
            COUNT(v.phone_number) AS phone_number_count
       FROM CORP_ACCT s
       LEFT OUTER JOIN voip_phone_number_pool v
            ON s.state = v.state
   GROUP BY s.state;
```

worked for me

Answer (score 1):

This mimics what you have now:

```
SQL> with voip_phone_number_pool (state, phone_number, status) as
  2    (select 'AZ', 1234, 3 from dual union all
  3     select 'AZ', 2232, 3 from dual union all
  4     select 'AZ', 4444, 3 from dual union all
  5     select 'AZ', 7756, 1 from dual union all
  6     --
  7     select 'CA', 9999, 1 from dual
  8    )
  9  select state,
 10         count(phone_number)
 11  from voip_phone_number_pool
 12  where status = 3
 13  group by state
 14  order by state;

ST COUNT(PHONE_NUMBER)
-- -------------------
AZ                   3

SQL>
```

There's no row for the `CA` state which has `status = 3`, so it isn't returned by that query.

What you could do, is to use *outer self-join* in such a manner:

```
SQL> with voip_phone_number_pool (state, phone_number, status) as
  2    (select 'AZ', 1234, 3 from dual union all
  3     select 'AZ', 2232, 3 from dual union all
  4     select 'AZ', 4444, 3 from dual union all
  5     select 'AZ', 7756, 1 from dual union all
  6     --
  7     select 'CA', 9999, 1 from dual
  8    ),
  9  states as
 10    (select distinct state from voip_phone_number_pool)
 11  select s.state,
 12         count(v.phone_number)
 13  from states s left join voip_phone_number_pool v on v.state = s.state 
 14                                                  and v.status = 3
 15  group by s.state
 16  order by s.state;

ST COUNT(V.PHONE_NUMBER)
-- ---------------------
AZ                     3
CA                     0

SQL>
```

- the `states` CTE selects all states
- it is then used in outer join with `voip_phone_number_pool`
- note that condition (`status = 3`) has to be moved into join (line #14); if you leave it in the `where` clause, you won't get desired result

Comment: Yea i think Im going to have to do this, thanks for helping with it.

Answer (score 0):

If there are no rows in the fact table (VOIP_PHONE_NUMBER_POOL) with a particular state, you will not get such a result from only querying that table.

You will need to join your fact table to a dimension table (a table with all possible states) in order to get the desired counts.

For example, assuming you have such a dimension table and it is named "state_info":

```
         SELECT s.state,
                COUNT(v.phone_number) AS phone_number_count
           FROM state_info s
LEFT OUTER JOIN voip_phone_number_pool v
                ON s.state = v.state
       GROUP BY s.state;
```

Comment: If the fact table does not exist, create one using a common table expression:

WITH state_info AS (
     SELECT 'AL' AS state FROM DUAL UNION ALL
     SELECT 'AK' AS state FROM DUAL UNION ALL
     ......
     SELECT 'WY' AS state FROM DUAL
     )
         SELECT s.state,
                COUNT(v.phone_number) AS phone_number_count
           FROM state_info s
LEFT OUTER JOIN voip_phone_number_pool v
                ON s.state = v.state
       GROUP BY s.state;

Comment: Thanks, I ended up creating a column in one of our tables to track States by and that worked